# How do I install Slackware on VMWare Fusion on OS X?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion, slackware

I have the Slackware ISO files but when I get to the install, I can't figure out where to choose the ISOs after setting the initial boot ISO.

Anyone installed this recently and can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very [carefully](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jbyrne/vmware.htm).

To select the ISO, when you see this dialog:

[image: install dialog]

Select `Use operating system installation disk image file`. From there it should go to a file browse dialog, where you can select the downloaded ISO.

If you need to switch ISO files in the middle of running. You can do that too. Look on the lower right hand corner of the window for the icon resembling a disk, right click (or `ctrl` click if you have but one button) and select from the menu:

[image: link text]

Comment: I read the question to mean that he's downloaded the 6 separate Slackware CD ISO's and he's not sure how to have VMWare Fusion switch among them during the installation process.

Comment: Hm, that's a good point. The Lower right hand corner has an icon for the virtual optical drive while running. Select that and there is the option for changing which ISO to use. I'll add some illustration if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not grab the appropriate single-DVD ISO from the [Slackware torrents page](http://www.slackware.com/getslack/torrents.php)?